# Oracle Error using loadjava (ORA-29532)

Tags: oracle, loadjava, ora-29532

When I try to load a jar containing an interface in Oracle12c thanks to this command:

`loadjava -v -r -u user@localhost:1521:SCM  -resolver "((* SCM) (* PUBLIC) (* -))"  C:\PATH\message-sender-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

All classes are well loaded but no one interface is known. I have this error:

```
ORA-29552: avertissement de vérification : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yyy/xxx/MessageSender
```

Any idea?

Regards.

Comment: You need to make sure `PATH` is correct in the file parameter in the loadjava command.

Comment: Thanks, I check it. Some classes of the jar are loaded, so the PATH is correct.